# What word or phrasal verb is used for describing the process of removing chalk from ones clothes with one's hands?

Tags: word-choice, phrasal-verbs

Let's say I someone accidentally leaned against a blackboard and got chalk stains on their clothes. What word or phrasal verb would you use to describe the process of removing the stains with one's hands. Would the phrase *brush off* fit the context? For example:

> You got chalk on your back. You had better **brush** it **off**.

Comment: Your proposal sounds perfect to me.

Comment: ***Expunging***.

Comment: “dust”, “pat”, “scrape”, “shake”, are all possible options, amongst many others. It depends on what word picture you want to paint. How is the person doing the action? Gently? Aggressively? With a brushing action? With a scraping action? Something else?

Comment: expunge means to remove a part of a text from a text.

Answer (score 1):

'Brushing off' is suitable for removing dust from a smooth surface. Since it's about clothes here, I'd suggest '**shaking** (the chalk dust) **off**. Here's a picture showing that very action which is referred to in the picture file name:
 [image]
https://previews.123rf.com/images/gstockstudio/gstockstudio1602/gstockstudio160200033/51617903-shake-it-off-close-up-of-young-handsome-man-in-sunglasses-shaking-off-invisible-dust-from-his-should.jpg

Comment: Everyone seemed to miss the *off* preposition except you.

Answer (score 0):

**To dust** and **to pat** come to my mind, as chalk on clothes resemble dust.

Comment: It's called 'chalk dust'. The verb 'to dust' is fine for this situation. It is a cliché to say that schoolteachers' clothes are covered in chalk dust.

Comment: It is not dust chalk. It is: to dust **off** the chalk from your back.